# Если ли смысл скачивать файлы в нескольких потоках?

Tags: многопоточность, загрузка

Планирую сделать скачивание файлов.

Например, нужно скачать 9 файлов. Стоит ли их скачивать в 3 потоках или в одном?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @andreycha Я вижу 2 противоположных мнения с одинаковым количеством голосов. Как я должен решить кто прав?

Answer (score 2):

С т.з. обращения к веб-серверам и получения с них информации -- стопроцентно имеет. Можно и по потоку на файл.

Однако если вы планируете сохранять скачанные файлы на диске, то надо понимать, что диск практически не параллелится. Какое-то ускорение вы получите, но нужно экспериментировать.

Если память позволяет, я бы максимально параллелизовал скачивание файлов в память, а затем установил небольшую степень параллелизации для сохранения на диск.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего нет. Если Ваш канал "**у**же" скорости, которую может отдать сайт, то хоть в 100 потоков качай, скорость не прибавить. Но некоторые сервера ограничивают скорость скачки для одного файла и при этом ограничивают ее сильно. В этом случае скачивать нескольких файлов одновременно может принести пользу (до тех пор, пока канала хватает). Если файлы качаются с разных серверов и Ваш канал явно шире возможности серверов, тогда есть смысл качать в несколько потоков (но по потоку на файл). Но при этом, главное не уперется в скорость диска.

Эта вся шумиха с закачкой файлов пошла с тех времен, когда интернет был медленный и тяжелый. Когда tcp/ip стек работал плохо. Был спутниковый интернет (да и мобильный который назывался CDS), который в один поток не мог пустить больше определенной скорости (от 2400 до 9600). Но  таких потоков могло быть много. И вот в этом случае скачка в много потоков давала реальное ускорение.